# Elm is not recognizing List

Tags: elm

I am learning elm from this book when i try build this project i always get
the error that  Cannot find variable `List`

link of book -: https://www.elm-tutorial.org/en/05-resources/02-models.html

```
**strong text**Cannot find variable `List`

12|         List players
        ^^^^
Maybe you want one of the following?

list
Just
Html.Attributes.list
Maybe.Just
```

Comment: We can't help unless we see all your code.

Comment: Try removing elm-stuff directory and run elm package install to re-install everything. Make sure elm-lang/core is in the elm-package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is inside the file `List.elm` in your `Players` folder, maybe you should change it to a lowercase `list`. That function is defined in that same file.

Try:

```
, list players
```

on line 12 of the file  `Players/List.elm`